# Symfony2 and FOSUserBUndle - force user to change password

Tags: symfony, passwords, fosuserbundle

I need to force users to change password at least every 30 days. How to start with it? I noted in database that table users has column `credentials_expire_at` and when it's set to past date such an user can't login and I thought of allowing password change in login form when message of expiration detected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it in this way:

1. Create `EventListener` to `onSecurityInteractiveLogin` event
2. Check the date
3. If it fails redirect to change password form

Look at this coderwall protip: http://coderwall.com/p/cfmbaq

Comment: I get a fatal error: `Cannot redeclare class LoginListener in D:\www\bon\src\Alden\BonBundle\Listener\LoginListener.php on line 13`. I just copied the code into this file (only moved first } after `protected $userManager;` to the end of file. I checked - in whole project there is no other occurrence of word `LoginListener`.

Comment: OK I got it - I forgot to add namespace.

Comment: How can I redirect in onSecurityInteractiveLogin to url routed as fos_user_change_password?

Comment: Add this to the listener:
    ``public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event) {
  if ($this->redirect != '') {
   $this->redirect = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $this->redirect);
   $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->redirect));
  }
 }``